# Using SAML 2.0 to authenticate from .net mvc to another site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

I've never used SAML before and am a bit confused.  I thought I could just base64 encode xml and a key and be on my way, but apparently its not that simple.

I have to send a SAMLRESPONSE to a post method

```
<form method="post" action="%ACS" ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="%RESPONSE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="%RELAYSTATE" />
     ...
</form>
```

The action is their URL and the SAMLRESPONSE I generate on my end with the certificare or IDP MEta data and the assertation. I thought I could encode my xml

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'ID='identifier_1'Version='2.0'IssueInstant='2004-12-05T09:22:05Z'Destination='https://sp.example.com/SAML2/SSO/POST'> <saml:Issuer>https://idp.example.org/SAML2</saml:Issuer> <samlp:Status> <samlp:StatusCode Value='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success'/> </samlp:Status> <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'ID='identifier_2'Version='2.0'IssueInstant='2004-12-05T09:22:05Z'> <saml:Issuer>https://idp.example.org/SAML2</saml:Issuer> <ds:Signature xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>...</ds:Signature> <saml:Subject> <saml:NameID Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameidformat:uid'> " + employeeID + " </saml:NameID> <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer'> <saml:SubjectConfirmationData Recipient='https://sp.example.com/SAML2/SSO/POST'NotOnOrAfter='2004-12-05T09:27:05Z'/> </saml:SubjectConfirmation> </saml:Subject> <saml:Conditions NotBefore='2004-12-05T09:17:05Z'NotOnOrAfter='2004-12-05T09:27:05Z'> <saml:AudienceRestriction> <saml:Audience>https://sp.example.com/SAML2</saml:Audience> </saml:AudienceRestriction> </saml:Conditions> <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant='2004-12-05T09:22:00Z'SessionIndex='identifier_2'> <saml:AuthnContext> <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:u nspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef> </saml:AuthnContext> </saml:AuthnStatement> </saml:Assertion> </samlp:Response>
```

The provider reccomended I use ADFS 3.0 but I'd like to avoid changing anything on server.  Is there a different package I could use to help all this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try and roll your own. Use a client side SAML stack e.g. [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

This stack talks SAML to an IDP like ADFS. You need to configure ADFS with the SAML parameters of your client side stack.